# .Net Frameworkにてアンダーバーを表示するために「&」を使用したが、デザイン上でしか表示されない

Tags: c#, .net

### 状況

.Net FrameworkにてButtonのTextの１文字にアンダーバーを表示させたく、`&` を使用したが、デザイン上でしか表示されず、デバッグをして実際の画面を見るとアンダーバーが消えてしまっています。

`UseMnemonic`は`True`です。

- デザイン
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
- デバッグ
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もしもデバッグ時にAltキーを押して下線が表示されるならば[簡単操作キーボードの設定](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/ease-of-access-keyboard-settings-on-windows-10)を確認してください。

スタート > 設定 > 簡単操作 > (左メニュー)キーボード

を開き、「キーボード ショートカットの動作を変更する」メニューの「アクセス キーが利用可能な場合は下線を表示する」がオフになっている場合はオンにすることで実行時に下線が表示されます。

[image: Ease of Access]

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えてくださった方法でできるようになりました。